# Which function can be used to show elements and which can be used to hide them?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I am looking for an Android Studio version of "gameobject.SetActive(true/false);" from Unity. Is there a one? If there is
how to call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the element you're referring to is a View then you would use setVisibility:

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //view is visible
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //view is invisible, but still takes up space
view.setVisibility(View.GONE); //view is no longer visible, and does not take up space
```